# Pygame: Moving an image around another image in a circular path

Tags: python, pygame

I know that there are already some solutions here but unfortunately they did not help me with my problem. I want to move a satellite image around a planet image in a circular path. I know how to move it in a line from left to right but I don't get it how to make the circle. This is my code so far

````
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from sys import exit
from math import sin
from math import cos


player_image = 'dragon-500px.png'


pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1080, 720), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption("Animate X!")
mouse_cursor = pygame.image.load(player_image).convert_alpha()
image_earth = pygame.image.load('Erde.jpg').convert()
image_earth = pygame.transform.scale(image_earth, (300,300))
image_earth_rect = image_earth.get_rect()
image_earth_rect.center = (540, 360)

radius = 100
center = (540, 360)

direction = pygame.math.Vector2(1,0)





clock = pygame.time.Clock()

speed = 300.0

x = 0 - mouse_cursor.get_width()

y = 10
while True:
    time_passed = clock.tick() / 1000.0
    moved_distance = time_passed * speed
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            exit()
    direction.rotate_ip(4)
    direction.normalize_ip()
    Satellite_pos = [int(i) for i in center + direction*radius]
    
    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    if x > screen.get_width():
        x = 0 - mouse_cursor.get_width()
    elif y > screen.get_height():
        y = 10
    screen.blit(mouse_cursor, (x, y))
    screen.blit(image_earth, image_earth_rect)
    
    x+=moved_distance
    
    y+= moved_distance
  
  
    pygame.display.update() ```
````

Comment: Related: [Rotation of a sprite on a circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517579/rotation-of-a-sprite-on-a-circle/65332120#65332120) and [Ship moves up and left faster than down and right when rotating in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62411259/ship-moves-up-and-left-faster-than-down-and-right-when-rotating-in-pygame/65347117#65347117)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute the position of the satellite dependent on an angle:

```py
angle = 0

# [...]

while True:
    # [...]

    center = image_earth_rect.center
    Satellite_pos = [center[0] + radius * cos(angle), center[1] + radius * sin(angle)]
    angle += 0.01

    # [...]
```